# PHP form value results in array

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP form that once it's filled it sends results back to my email as a .csv file. I am having an issue with a value in my form coming back as "array" I have tried several things but I haven't had any luck finding where the error is coming from. Any suggestions? I am going a little nuts here

```
        <p>
       <label for="Candidacy" style="font-weight:bold;"><span class="asterisk">*</span>Degree Candidacy:</label><br/>
        <span class="errormessage Candidacy"><?php echo $CandidacyErr;?></span>
            <select size="4" name="Candidacy[]" id="Candidacy"> 
                <option value="JD Candidate" <?php if (isset($_POST['Candidacy']) && in_array('JD-Candidate', $_POST['Candidacy']))  echo ' selected="selected"';?> >Candidate 1</option>

                <option value="Joint JD/LLM Candidate" <?php if (isset($_POST['Candidacy']) && in_array('Joint-JD-LLM-Candidate', $_POST['Candidacy']))  echo ' selected="selected"';?> >Candidate 2</option>

                <option value="LLM Candidate" <?php if (isset($_POST['Candidacy']) && in_array('LLM-Candidate', $_POST['Candidacy']))  echo ' selected="selected"';?> >Candidate3</option>

                <option value="MJ Candidate" <?php if (isset($_POST['Candidacy']) && in_array('MJ-Candidate', $_POST['Candidacy']))  echo ' selected="selected"';?> >Candidate 4</option>

            </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: the name of the select is Candidacy[] which makes it array, remove []

Comment: ^ unless you have multiple `"name="Candidacy"` select fields

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! By getting rid of the [] my issue was fixed. One last thing is I have been trying to have these options as clickables but so far I haven't been able to make them work. Any suggestions for making them clickable? thanks a lot! <3